# How to install and use PyOCR in a virtual environment on Windows' Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda, ocr, virtual-environment

I would like to perform text recognition on pictures using Python. I've decided to try PyOCR with Tesseract.
I use Anaconda on a Windows machine, but the code should be easily deployable on any environment.
So I've created a virtual environment called 'ocr_server'.

If I install all required packages in my machine, the first steps work, but if I only intall them in the virtualenv, it doesn't.

What I've tried so far :

- Installation (in the Anaconda's shell):

```
    conda create -n ocr_server anaconda
    conda activate ocr_server
    conda install -c conda-forge tesseract  # I assume the exe file (found here: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) is not necessary
    conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract
```

Then I've downloaded language files on https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files, and placed them in the tessdata folder of my virtualenv.

```
    pip install pyocr
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name=ocr_server  # To use it in JupyterLab
```

- Use (in a notebook on JupyterLab):

```
    from PIL import Image
    import sys

    import pyocr
    import pyocr.builders
#    import pytesseract

    tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
    tools
```

Result: There isn't any tool detected. But if I install tesseract, pytesseract and pyocr in my machine (and not only in the virtualenv), I can use Tesseract.

What could I try to solve this problem?

Thanks in avance.

Comment: It looks like the `pyocr.get_available_tools()` is checking for the environment variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` being defined. I don't see this being exported in the `tesseract` package, so you may have to define it yourself. See [the docs on defining env vars during activation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).